# Heroku: Deploying express js and reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have a project that uses express and react. I'm deploying it to heroku but after running `git push`, I receive an error in `heroku logs`. I go to the specified webpage and it says that it cannot find a buildpack. What do I do? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Docker containers have been invented to solve this type of deployment issues among other problems. You can build both React app and Express to run inside a container. Then verify the container is running locally. Finally deploy the container to Heroku. It takes 7 commands to do all that, see [here](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react#using-heroku) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

you need to go this way: **Settings -> Add buildpack -> node.js**
don't forget, that this is only start and you may need to add some scripts in your package.json file for heroku deployment process

Comment: I have this in the server package.json "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",

Comment: Did you add the buildpack in Heroku though? You need to put it in both package.json and in Heroku, as Heroku won't go looking for your script in package.json if it doesn't know what to look for.

Comment: i added through dashboard

Comment: what do i do now?